# getting the current user with Django drf and simple jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I was trying to get the current user with rest framework and simple jwt

I'm new to Django and I wrote a simple view that does(ish) the job

```
  class UserDetail(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication,]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
```

but for some reason when I post the user credentials to the endpoint in postman it says

```
    {
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
    }
```

but when I remove the ==>         authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication,] and
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

it works and gite the current user, my question is is this the right way of doing it, and are there any risks in doing it this way and if their is a better and more secure way of doing it. thanks in advance!!

[image]
this is the screenshot of the postM request data

and this is the URL for the class:-

```
path('detail/', UserDetail.as_view({'get':'list'}), name="blacklist"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the access token in the request.
If you are not confident in setting up simplejwt, follow [this guide](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html):

If you use postman to test the API, you can provide Authorization details like shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng4Br.png)

If you are using any other medium to send requests, then you can add Authorization in the request's header: `{"Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"}`

Comment: I have already set up simple jwt by following a tut video but how would I get the details of the authenticated user, the above code works but doesn't validate the access_token it just simply returns the user

Comment: Just to be sure, are you passing the credentials in the `UserDetail` viewset's url or in `TokenObtainPairView` view?

Comment: how do i do that can you give me the snippet??

Comment: can you edit your main post and put the screenshot of your postman with URL and params/data?

Comment: I edited and put the image per your request

Comment: if you were asking for the data in the params tab in postman it's completely empty

Comment: Ohh, you mean to say that you need to get the detail of the authenticated user who sent the request?

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to generate the token. All you have to do is pass the token in Postman url `localhost:8000/detail/` and under the Authorization tab, select the `Bearer token` and paste the token which has been generated and send it. Under `settings.py` edit Simple JWT settings by adding `Bearer` after `JWT` in `AUTH_HEADER_TYPES`. Hope this works for you.